# Userform time format problems

Tags: excel, time, format, vba

Ok, so i have been working on a project for a while now. And its almost done. But i keep having small issues that i cant solve. This time its a formatting issue.

Short and simple:
I have a table in sheet1(database) of information that i display in a userform (see image) [image: Sheet1] [image: Userform]
There are several approaches to add a new line in the database, you can add it manually by filling all the empty text boxes, or you can double click an existing row and the text boxes fill them self. My problem is when i double clicking existing row, time format changes. see image. [image: image2]

I solved that using this code:

```
Private Sub Reg5_Change()
Reg5.Value = Format(Reg5.Value, "hh:mm")
End Sub
```

But then i have trouble doing it the manually way. When i try to type in time i end up getting 00:00 and having trouble changing it.

Is there a way to solve this so i can use both methods for adding new row in database?

Other questions:
I want the textbox ETA to contain ETD + EET. [image: Image3]

I tried this with a result of 08:02 when ETD = 08:00 and EET = 02:00. Seems like EET is added as minutes.

```
Private Sub Reg7_AfterUpdate()
Reg7.Value = Reg5.Value + Reg6.Value
end sub
```

Update:

```
Private Sub Reg7_Change()
Dim etd As String: etd = Reg5.Value
Dim eet As String: eet = Reg6.Value

Dim detd As date
Dim deet As date

detd = TimeSerial(Split(etd, ":")(0), Split(etd, ":")(1), 0)
deet = TimeSerial(Split(eet, ":")(0), Split(eet, ":")(1), 0)
Reg7.Value = detd + deet
end sub
```

Getting this error [image: Error]
But as you can see in the image the time is correct and that part is working correct.

hope there is someone out there who can help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the part for "*I tried this with a result of 08:02 when ETD = 08:00 and EET = 02:00. Seems like EET is added as minutes.*"

Try to use `TimeSerial()` declare variables as date and pass variables to it.
This is a simple example:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim etd As String: etd = "08:00"
    Dim eet As String: eet = "02:00"

    Dim detd    As Date
    Dim deet    As Date

    detd = TimeSerial(Split(etd, ":")(0), Split(etd, ":")(1), 0)
    deet = TimeSerial(Split(eet, ":")(0), Split(eet, ":")(1), 0)

    Debug.Print detd + deet '10:00:00

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it. Not 100% sure how to use it and where to put it. But i have some understand whats happening in the code, so this will probably help me. Thanks again :)

Comment: Tested your code and modifyed it a littlebit. see my original post. It does what it should do now. but i get error, i think it might be because of wrong time format ? any idea how i can change the format?

Comment: @JoakimGrønstrand - to change the format select the cell, right button, properties, change format. To change it via VBA, record a macro while doing it and see the code.

Comment: Can you see my recent update on my problem and see if you can see whats causing the error?

Comment: @JoakimGrønstrand - I suppose that the `Reg5.Value` does not have twice the `:` in it.

Comment: Thats correct! Reg5 and 6 has format "hh:mm". what changes should i do with my code then? thx

Comment: @JoakimGrønstrand - try to convert it to string and see how it looks like.

Comment: having no luck with that either. There is probably something stupid im not seeing..

Comment: Write `MsgBox (Cstr(Reg5.Value))`, @JoakimGrønstrand

Comment: Sry, for my late answer, I found a solution after some time.Thx for the help!